# ASP.NET MVC @Url.Action includes current route data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Suppose I:

- Have a route `{controller}/{action}/{id}` in my `Global.asax` file.
- A Controller `Foo` and Action `Bar(String id)` returning a view.
- A very simple View containing a URL rendered by `@Url.Action("bar", "foo")` - explicitly NOT specifying an `id`.
- If I browse to `/foo/bar/test`, the view will show the rendered URL as `/foo/bar/test`. I would have expected that it should be `/foo/bar` as I didn't specify a value for `id`.

Why would it include the current id even when I didn't specify it, and is there any way of preventing this (apart from 'hard-coding' the URL directly)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Url.Action adds current route values to generated url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133223/asp-net-mvc-url-action-adds-current-route-values-to-generated-url)

Answer (score 1):

You did specify the value for id when you put `/foo/bar/test` in the browser address bar. You are essentially calling the method `Bar` with the parameter "test" in your foo controller. Your simple view is irrelevant when you browse directly.

To answer your last question you may need to have a re-look at the way you are using MVC.

Comment: I did specify the id when browsing to the page, but not when I defined the link using Url.Action. IMHO, the Url.Action should be building a link to my requirements, not 'hunting' for extra values. That means that I cannot create a link to /foo/bar from /foo/bar/test. I noticed this when I was trying to post a form to /foo/bar/ from /foo/bar/test.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I believe this is a regression bug in MVC3, as discussed by Phil Haack here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx</s>

This is the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7133304/27938

Comment: I don't think it is as I only have one optional url parameter